# Extending Twig, are custom handlers for the dot operator (getAttribute) possible?

Tags: twig, twig-extension

Using Twig 3.0, I was wondering if it is possible to create Twig extensions that intervene when the dot operator is being processed?

So, suppose I have this expression

```
{{ myRecord.myField }}
```

and it won't work even though `myRecord` is a known thing, because it doesn't have a field called `myField`.

But I would want Twig to run my own custom extension code to figure out what to use for `.myField`, is that possible? How?

I know this can be achieved with different notations using a function or filter (e.g. `myRecord|getCustomField(myField)`), but I want to keep the dot notation because I feel it's particularly adequate for my purposes.

Comment: Sure, this is possible. I'd suggest you fork your own `twig` repo and adjust how templats are compiled. Some information can be found [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/internals.html) - No seriously, why would you want to do this?

Comment: I am not using Twig as usual to render HTML, I am using it as a backbone of a low-code language. It's working great for my purposes, BTW. My end-users are actually developers, and this would allow me to create some short-hand fields to access frequently used information from complex objects.

Comment: Look at the final note on the page, it's possible to create and inject your own compiler. The best bet is to look into that route

Comment: I've seen that, I guess that I need more help to get that going. I was hoping someone could provide a working example, or point me to the exact place that I need to tweak...

Answer (score 0):

The `CoreExtension` supports `get*`, `is*`, `has*` method lookups for the dot.

https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/3.x/src/Extension/CoreExtension.php#L1563

So if your class has a `myRecord::getMyField` method you can access it via `myRecord.myField` in Twig.

Another option is to use the `__call` magic method: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call

The more complex and flexible approach that doesn't require altering the `myRecord` class would involve writing a custom Extension to replace nodes. Here's a simple example that you can modify to create MethodCall nodes on the class, for example.

```php
$twig->addExtension(new class extends Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension {
      public function getNodeVisitors(): array {
          return [
              new class implements Twig\NodeVisitor\NodeVisitorInterface {
                  public function enterNode(Node $node, Environment $env): Node {
                      return $node;
                  }

                  public function leaveNode(Node $node, Environment $env): ?Node {
                      if (!$node instanceof Twig\Node\Expression\GetAttrExpression) {
                          return $node;
                      }

                      if ('myRecord' !== $node->getNode('node')->getAttribute('name')) {
                          return $node;
                      }

                      // Custom lookup logic goes here...
                      $attribute = $node->getNode('attribute')->getAttribute('value');

                      $node->setNode('attribute', new Twig\Node\Expression\ConstantExpression('get_' . $attribute, 0));

                      return $node;
                  }

                  public function getPriority(): int {
                      return 1;
                  }
              }
          ];
      }
  });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. It'll take me some time to digest this, but your answer definitely leaves me closer to what I need. I'll see what I can come up with.